# Поменять местами значения

Tags: python

Как можно поменять местами значения ключей кроме последнего?

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Anton", "age": 23, "order": 1}
{"id": 2, "name": "Nick", "age": 19, "order": 2}
```

Хочу что бы получилось:

```
{"id": 2, "name": "Nick", "age": 19, "order": 1}
{"id": 1, "name": "Anton", "age": 23, "order": 2}
```

Comment: `a['order'], b['order'] = b['order'], a['order']`

Comment: это гениально!!

Comment: все гениальное - просто

Comment: @entithat Можете помочь еще с 1 вопросом?

Comment: ну конкретнее..

Comment: @entithat получаю данные в методе get из БД в виде словаря, обрабатываю их, получаю два новых словаря, как можно обратно в БД эти данные вернуть?

Comment: Зависимо какая бд, как вы с ней работаете. Просто записать надо. Загуглите) Очень общий вопрос у вас